# Biblatex: Standard way to cite a volume of a series in a collection

Tags: biblatex

Is there a standard way to cite a volume of a multi-volume series that appeared again in a multi-volume 'collected works' edition. 
Like, I wanna cite 'Volume 6 of Series 6 of the collected Works of G.W. Leibniz'. There are 53 volumes total, but for each series, the numbering starts again from 1. So, the Output should be sthg like that: Akademie Edition, Ser. III, Vol. IX, p256

I could solve it with using shorthands, I guess. my .bib file so far Looks like that:

**EDIT: MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
backend=biber, 
style=verbose]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{A,
Author = {Leibniz, Gottfried Wilhelm},
Title = {S{\"a}mtliche Schriften und Briefe},
Volumes = {53},
Year = {1923-}}

@book{A:VI:vi,
Author = {Leibniz, Gottfried Wilhelm},
Maintitle = {S{\"a}mtliche Schriften und Werke},
Series = {Philosophische Schriften},
Number= {6},
Title = {Nouveaux Essais},
Volume = {6},
Year = {1962}}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{Title}

\cite[123]{A}

\cite[123]{A}
***

\volcite[c.f.]{2}[123]{A}

***

\cite[123]{A:VI:vi}

\cite[123]{A:VI:vi}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: hi! thx. sure. uploaded the MWE. but, my questions is more a general one.

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to what you want to achieve. Could you add an example of what you would like to get with these `.bib` entries? (I can't see any "Akademie Edition", "Ser" etc. in your bib file.)

Comment: hi! I was looking for sthg like an extended \volcite command that let's me cite both volume and series. (e.g. XYZ, Series VI, Volume XIX, page 123)

basically, what I have here is a book with in a multi-volume book within a multi-volume book.

Comment: Maybe the package [`biblatex-source-division`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-source-division) as in [Print numbered paragraph after title with Biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/212217/35864) can help you.