# Print numbered paragraph after title with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

My question is related with Biber and Biblatex (latest versions). I need to quote the number of a paragraph of an old Christian text which is published within a book printed nowadays.

More clearly, I'm working with this Biblatex item (it's in Italian):

```
@INBOOK{Clemente1984Lettera,
  author = {Clemente di Roma},
  title = {Lettera di Clemente Romano ai Corinti},
  year = {1984},
  booktitle = {I Padri apostolici},
  editor = {Quaquarelli, Antonio},
  location = {Roma},
  pages = {41-92},
  publisher = {Città Nuova}
}
```

I quote it in a common LaTex file with the BibTex key:

```
\cite[42]{Clemente1985Lettera}
```

With a humanistic Biblatex style, the final citation is:

Clemente di Roma, *Lettera di Clemente Romano ai Corinti*, in "I Padri apostolici", edited by A. Quaquarelli, Roma 1985, p. 42.

Anyway, I need to quote specifically the n. 2 of the letter of Clement, so I have to print this number just after the title "Lettera di Clemente Romano ai Corinti". So, I'd like to have this citation:

Clemente di Roma, *Lettera di Clemente Romano ai Corinti*, n. 2, in "I Padri apostolici", edited by A. Quaquarelli, Roma 1985, p. 42.

Now, I can find no Biblatex field to store the "n. 2" text, and no way to print it after the title. Of course, I could create a specific item in the bibliographic file in which the title field, or another one which is supposed to follow it, contains the "n. 2" indication. Anyway, this solution is very bad to me, because I should fill my archive with items of specific citations, and not of single titles.

What I'm looking for is what I've already implemented in the Bibfilex citations system (https://sites.google.com/site/bibfilex), which is moreover far less powerful that Biber: the possibility to add a pipe in the postnote of a BibTex key to separate a possible indication of a number of a paragraph, to be printed just after the title, from the pages of the volume. So a key like that

```
\cite[2|42]{Clemente1985Lettera}
```

should print

Clemente di Roma, *Lettera di Clemente Romano ai Corinti*, n. 2, in "I Padri apostolici", edited by A. Quaquarelli, Roma 1985, p. 42.

Anybody knows how to do that with Biber and Biblatex?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a complete MWE to your question, otherwise it would be difficult for us to help you. http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Thank you. Is now the question more clear?

Answer (score 2):

The package [biblatex-source-division](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-source-division) by Maïeul Rouquette, who is also active on this site as [Maïeul](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7712/ma%C3%AFeul), implements something very similar.

You can use `\cite[(part)page]{key}` to give the number. By default this  is printed as-is after the title, technically it is put into the `titleaddon` field.

So you probably need something like

```
\cite[(\bibstring{number}~2)42]{Clemente1984Lettera}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
        style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex-source-division}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@INBOOK{Clemente1984Lettera,
  author = {Clemente di Roma},
  title = {Lettera di Clemente Romano ai Corinti},
  year = {1984},
  booktitle = {I Padri apostolici},
  editor = {Quaquarelli, Antonio},
  location = {Roma},
  pages = {41-92},
  publisher = {Città Nuova},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\renewcommand*\newunitpunct{\addcomma\space}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite[(\bibstring{number}~2)42]{Clemente1984Lettera}
\end{document}
```

[image]