# Citing editions of medieval texts with biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

In citing medieval texts using `biblatex-chicago`, I often want to refer to the author and title of a book, then print a section or paragraph number, then the book's *editor* (i.e., the modern editor who collated the manuscripts and produced the version of the text I am using), and only then the page number or, in the (common) case of a multivolume edition, volume number and page number. Is there a citation command that would let me do this (along the lines of *Chicago Manual of Style* 14.260)?

Here is an example of what I am looking for. The first citation should be:

> Photios, *Bibliotheca*, cod. 172, ed. René Henry (Paris: Les Belles Lettres, 1959–1991), vol. 2, p. 169.

Then subsequent citations should be:

> Photios, *Bibliotheca*, cod. 172, ed. Henry, vol. 2, p. 169.

To do this, I would like to be able to write:

```
Photios, \emph{Bibliotheca}, cod.\ 172, \editorvolcite{2}[169]{photios:bibliotheca:henry}.
```

with a `.bib` file containing:

```
@book{photios:bibliotheca:henry,
Address = {Paris},
Author = {Photios},
Booktitle = {Bibliothèque},
Editor = {Henry, René},
Entrysubtype = {primary},
Note = {index by Jacques Schamp},
Publisher = {Les Belles Lettres},
Title = {Bibliothèque},
Volumes = {9},
Year = {1959--1991}}
```

Perhaps there is already a command like `\editorvolcite`?

(Likewise, for the case of a single-volume work, there would be a command `\editorcite` that only prints "`editor`, p. `pagenumber`".)

---

**Update 2017-09-09**

MWE (using `\volcite` rather than the desired `\editorvolcite` in order to satisfy the "W" part of MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{editor-cite.bib}

\begin{document}

Photios, \emph{Bibliotheca}, cod.\ 172,\mancite{}
\volcite{2}[169]{photios:bibliotheca:henry}.

Photios, \emph{Bibliotheca}, cod.\ 172,\mancite{}
\volcite{2}[169]{photios:bibliotheca:henry}.

\end{document}
```

---

**Update 2017-09-10**

Based on the comments, I have looked into `biblatex-source-division` with the usage described in [Print numbered paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212217/print-numbered-paragraph-after-title-with-biblatex) and tried to implement it. But it still doesn't quite do what I'm trying to do.

Here is my MWE version 2:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{biblatex-source-division}

\renewcommand*\newunitpunct{\addcomma\space}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{photios:bibliotheca:henry,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {Photios},
    Booktitle = {Bibliothèque},
    Editor = {Henry, René},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Note = {index by Jacques Schamp},
    Publisher = {Les Belles Lettres},
    Title = {Bibliothèque},
    Volumes = {9},
    Year = {1959--1991}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

1st time:
\volcite{2}[(cod.\ 172)169]{photios:bibliotheca:henry}.

2nd time:
\volcite{2}[(cod.\ 172)169]{photios:bibliotheca:henry}.

\mancite{}

Again after \verb`\mancite`:
\volcite{2}[(cod.\ 172)169]{photios:bibliotheca:henry}.

\end{document}
```

The result for the first-time citation is perfect. But I think the following citation should be simply "ibid." though "ibid., cod. 172" is not so bad either. But the real problem is that the (full) short citation after `\mancite` lacks the editor. Here is a clip of my result:

[image: Result of MWE v2]

Is there a way to turn the last one into the following?

> Photios, *Bibliothèque*, cod. 172, ed. Henry, vol. 2, p. 169.

---

**Update 2017-09-21**

As I mentioned in a comment down below, the solution kindly proposed by @moewe results in a slight bug when it interacts with complicated features of `biblatex-chicago`, in particular `shorthandibid`. Here is a new MWE that produces a spurious comma resulting in

> ibid.,

where there should simply be

> ibid.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes,
        alldates=       comp,
        backend=        biber,
        bibwarn=        false,
        cmsdate=        both, % reprints: print `origdate` as well as `year`
        compresspages=  true,
        doi=            false,
        eprint=     false,
        ibidtracker=        true,
        inheritshorthand,       % feature added for me by D.Fussner
        isbn=           false,
        mincrossrefs =  2,
        shorthandibid,
        strict=     true,
        url=            false,
        usetranslator=  true,
        uniquename= true
    ]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{biblatex-source-division}

\AtEveryCite{\renewcommand*\newunitpunct{\addcomma\space}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{photios:bibliotheca:henry,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {Photios},
    Booktitle = {Bibliothèque},
    Editor = {Henry, René},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Note = {index by Jacques Schamp},
    Publisher = {Les Belles Lettres},
    Title = {Bibliothèque},
    Volumes = {9},
    Year = {1959--1991},
    options = {medinfo},
}
@book{loci:communes:ihm,
    Author = {{ps.-Maximos the Confessor}},
    Booktitle = {Erste kritische Edition einer Redaktion des sacro-profanen Florilegiums Loci communes},
    Editor = {Ihm, Sibylle},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Keywords = {Loci communes},
    Publisher = {Franz Steiner Verlag},
    Shorthand = {\emph{Loc.comm.}\ Ihm},
    Shorttitle = {Loci communes},
    Sortname = {Maximos the Confessor},
    Title = {Erste kritische Edition einer Redaktion des sacro-profanen Florilegiums Loci communes},
    Year = {2001}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newtoggle{bbx:ar:medinfo}
\togglefalse{bbx:ar:medinfo}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{medinfo}[true]{\settoggle{bbx:ar:medinfo}{#1}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \usebibmacro{allshort+firstcite+xref}%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{reference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{mvreference}}%
  {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{magazine}\AND\NOT%
      \ifentrytype{periodical}}% Simplify .bib creation
    {\ifuseauthor%
      {\ifboolexpr{%
          not test {\iffieldundef{shortjournal}}%
          and
          ((
          test {\ifcitation}%
          and
          togl {cms@citejtabb}%
          )
          or
          (
          test {\ifbibliography}%
          and
          togl {cms@bibjtabb}%
          ))
        }%
        {\printfield[shortjournal]{shortjournal}\newcunit}%
        {\printfield[journaltitle]{journaltitle}\newcunit}}%
      {}}%
    {\ifentrytype{manual}%
      {\printlist{organization}\isdot\newcunit}%
      {}}}%
  {\ifboolexpr{%
      test {\ifciteidem}%
      and
      not test {\ifbibliography}%
      and
      not test {\iffirstonpage}%
      and
      not togl {cms@noidem}%
      and
      not togl {cms@headlessnote}%
    }%
    {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}%
      \classicpunct}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon}%
      {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}%
        \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
      {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon?}%
        {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}?%
          \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
        {\printnames{labelname}%\usebibmacro{choose+labelname}%
          \isdot\classicpunct}}}}%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    togl {cms@allshort}%
    or
    test {\ifbibliography}%
  }%
  {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%
  {\printtext[cmshyperlink]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%#
  \iftoggle{bbx:ar:medinfo}
    {\newcunit
     \printfield{titleaddon}%
     \newcunit
     \usebibmacro{cbyeditor:short}}
  {}}

\DeclareNameFormat{family}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\renewbibmacro*{cbyeditor:short}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}%
    {}%
    {\usebibmacro{cbytypestrg}{editor}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[family]{editor}%
     \newcunit}%
  \usebibmacro{cbyeditorx:short}}

\renewbibmacro*{cbyeditorx:short}{%
  \ifnameundef{editora}%
    {}%
    {\usebibmacro{cbytypestrg}{editora}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[family]{editora}%
     \newcunit}%
  \ifnameundef{editorb}%
    {}%
    {\usebibmacro{cbytypestrg}{editorb}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[family]{editorb}%
     \newcunit}%
  \ifnameundef{editorc}%
    {}%
    {\usebibmacro{cbytypestrg}{editorc}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[family]{editorc}%
     \newcunit}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{editor-cite with volume}

1st time:
\volcite{2}[(cod.\ 172)169]{photios:bibliotheca:henry}.

2nd time:
\volcite{2}[(cod.\ 172)169]{photios:bibliotheca:henry}.

After \mancite\verb`\mancite`:
\volcite{2}[(cod.\ 172)169]{photios:bibliotheca:henry}.

Again: \volcite{2}[(cod.\ 172)169\textsubscript{11}]{photios:bibliotheca:henry}.

\section{problem with shorthand/ibid}

1st time: \cite[3]{loci:communes:ihm}.

2nd time: \cite[3]{loci:communes:ihm}.

After \mancite\verb`\mancite`: \cite[3]{loci:communes:ihm}.

Again: \cite[3]{loci:communes:ihm}.

Without final period in source: \cite[3]{loci:communes:ihm}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you use the `note` style? An MWE would help us get started more quickly, even though your question is fairly clear without one.

Comment: I think that [biblatex-source-division](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-source-division) will do what you want.

Comment: Have a look at [Print numbered paragraph after title with Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/212217/35864) for `biblatex-source-division`.

Comment: Thanks to @DavidPurton and @moewe for the suggestion. I've looked into `biblatex-source-division` and found that it seems promising for what I want to do, but I haven't yet managed to make it quite work consistently. I will now update my question accordingly.

Comment: As a side question, will `\renewcommand*\newunitpunct{\addcomma\space}` have unintended consequences elsewhere?

Comment: Is used in many places in the bibliography (it is the default punctuation between any two bits of information - in some prominent places it is overridden by other explicit punctuation) and rarely in (full) citations. Changing it can cause changes in quite a bit of places.

Comment: I see what you mean, @moewe: I just added `\printbibliography` to the end and saw that it replaces the periods that should be there with commas, both for `photios:bibliotheca:henry` and `sigfridsson`. Might there be a way to enforce commas *only* in the case of `\cite`/`\volcite`/etc. commands that make use of `biblatex-source-division`, but never in the bibliography/list of references?

Comment: You could do `\AtEveryCite{\renewcommand*\newunitpunct{\addcomma\space}}`. `biblatex-chicago` already uses commas in citations more extensively, but since its codebase is so big another solution will need to redefine lots of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your last MWE using `biblatex-source-division` we can implement a new option called `medinfo` that interacts with `biblatex-source-division` and also prints the editor.

The necessary changes are quite long since the macros of `biblatex-chicago` are quite complicated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{biblatex-source-division}

\renewcommand*\newunitpunct{\addcomma\space}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{photios:bibliotheca:henry,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {Photios},
    Booktitle = {Bibliothèque},
    Editor = {Henry, René},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Note = {index by Jacques Schamp},
    Publisher = {Les Belles Lettres},
    Title = {Bibliothèque},
    Volumes = {9},
    Year = {1959--1991},
    options = {medinfo},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newtoggle{bbx:ar:medinfo}
\togglefalse{bbx:ar:medinfo}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{medinfo}[true]{\settoggle{bbx:ar:medinfo}{#1}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \usebibmacro{allshort+firstcite+xref}%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{reference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{mvreference}}%
  {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{magazine}\AND\NOT%
      \ifentrytype{periodical}}% Simplify .bib creation
    {\ifuseauthor%
      {\ifboolexpr{%
          not test {\iffieldundef{shortjournal}}%
          and
          ((
          test {\ifcitation}%
          and
          togl {cms@citejtabb}%
          )
          or
          (
          test {\ifbibliography}%
          and
          togl {cms@bibjtabb}%
          ))
        }%
        {\printfield[shortjournal]{shortjournal}\newcunit}%
        {\printfield[journaltitle]{journaltitle}\newcunit}}%
      {}}%
    {\ifentrytype{manual}%
      {\printlist{organization}\isdot\newcunit}%
      {}}}%
  {\ifboolexpr{%
      test {\ifciteidem}%
      and
      not test {\ifbibliography}%
      and
      not test {\iffirstonpage}%
      and
      not togl {cms@noidem}%
      and
      not togl {cms@headlessnote}%
    }%
    {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}%
      \classicpunct}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon}%
      {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}%
        \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
      {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon?}%
        {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}?%
          \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
        {\printnames{labelname}%\usebibmacro{choose+labelname}%
          \isdot\classicpunct}}}}%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    togl {cms@allshort}%
    or
    test {\ifbibliography}%
  }%
  {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%
  {\printtext[cmshyperlink]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%#
  \iftoggle{bbx:ar:medinfo}
    {\newcunit
     \printfield{titleaddon}%
     \newcunit
     \usebibmacro{cbyeditor}}
  {}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
1st time:
\volcite{2}[(cod.\ 172)169]{photios:bibliotheca:henry}.

2nd time:
\volcite{2}[(cod.\ 172)169]{photios:bibliotheca:henry}.

\cite{sigfridsson}

Again after \verb`\mancite`:
\volcite{2}[(cod.\ 172)169]{photios:bibliotheca:henry}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Subsequent non-ibid citation 'Photios, *Bibliothèque*, cod. 172, ed. René Henry, vol. 2, p. 169.']

If you want only the last name, replace the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` block with the longer

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \usebibmacro{allshort+firstcite+xref}%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{reference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{mvreference}}%
  {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{magazine}\AND\NOT%
      \ifentrytype{periodical}}% Simplify .bib creation
    {\ifuseauthor%
      {\ifboolexpr{%
          not test {\iffieldundef{shortjournal}}%
          and
          ((
          test {\ifcitation}%
          and
          togl {cms@citejtabb}%
          )
          or
          (
          test {\ifbibliography}%
          and
          togl {cms@bibjtabb}%
          ))
        }%
        {\printfield[shortjournal]{shortjournal}\newcunit}%
        {\printfield[journaltitle]{journaltitle}\newcunit}}%
      {}}%
    {\ifentrytype{manual}%
      {\printlist{organization}\isdot\newcunit}%
      {}}}%
  {\ifboolexpr{%
      test {\ifciteidem}%
      and
      not test {\ifbibliography}%
      and
      not test {\iffirstonpage}%
      and
      not togl {cms@noidem}%
      and
      not togl {cms@headlessnote}%
    }%
    {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}%
      \classicpunct}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon}%
      {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}%
        \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
      {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon?}%
        {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}?%
          \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
        {\printnames{labelname}%\usebibmacro{choose+labelname}%
          \isdot\classicpunct}}}}%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    togl {cms@allshort}%
    or
    test {\ifbibliography}%
  }%
  {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%
  {\printtext[cmshyperlink]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%#
  \iftoggle{bbx:ar:medinfo}
    {\newcunit
     \printfield{titleaddon}%
     \newcunit
     \usebibmacro{cbyeditor:short}}
  {}}

\DeclareNameFormat{family}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\newbibmacro*{cbyeditor:short}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}%
    {}%
    {\usebibmacro{cbytypestrg}{editor}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[family]{editor}%
     \newcunit}%
  \usebibmacro{cbyeditorx:short}}

\newbibmacro*{cbyeditorx:short}{%
  \ifnameundef{editora}%
    {}%
    {\usebibmacro{cbytypestrg}{editora}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[family]{editora}%
     \newcunit}%
  \ifnameundef{editorb}%
    {}%
    {\usebibmacro{cbytypestrg}{editorb}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[family]{editorb}%
     \newcunit}%
  \ifnameundef{editorc}%
    {}%
    {\usebibmacro{cbytypestrg}{editorc}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[family]{editorc}%
     \newcunit}}
\makeatother
```

---

The additional comma after 'ibid.' was introduced by `biblatex-source-division`. I don't think this package was written with `biblatex-chicago` in mind.

As it turns out this could be considered a bug in `biblatex-source-division`. I have reported the issue at https://github.com/maieul/biblatex-source-division/issues/2 and Maïeul has reacted really swiftly. Version 2.4.2 of the package has a fix for this problem, this version is available in MikTeX and TeX live now.

(An earlier version of this answer included an ad-hoc fix for the problem. That fix is not necessary any longer with the updated version of `biblatex-source-division`, so I removed it, it can be found in the edit history.)

Comment: Wonderful, thank you, @moewe. Would it be possible to tweak it to print only the editor's short name (in this case "ed. Henry" instead of "ed. René Henry") for repeated citations?

Comment: @AlexRoberts It is possible (but possibly inconsistent), see the edit, please.

Comment: In my original question I had been searching for a cite command that would print only the editor's name (or editor plus Address, Publisher, and Year) followed by page or vol/page. Sometimes it would be useful to be able to do just that. Is that simple to do? Perhaps a command for it already exists and I just haven't found it in the `biblatex-chicago` manual?

Comment: @AlexRoberts I don't think such a command exists, you'd have to roll your own. `\citename{foo}{editor}` gives you the editor, but not the volume, you could define a volcite version of the editor citation...

Comment: Now that I have tried out this method for a while, I have found that I was probably too hasty in declaring this the answer to my question. In particular, I noticed that even the restricted comma declaration causes strange things to happen; for example when I cite a primary source with a defined Shorthand using `biblatex-chicago`'s feature that replaces repeated `shorthand`s with "ibid.", an extra comma appears after the period even when it is at the end of a sentence. So this seems like an unreliable way to achieve it. Something using `\citename{foo}{editor}` would probably be better.

Comment: @AlexRoberts Could you add the problematic reference to your MWE in your question (along with the incorrect output and what you expect)?

Comment: @AlexRoberts I will gladly investigate the issues you raise. But I would need something to reproduce the problem. Can you prepare an MWE?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have just posted the new MWE.

Comment: @AlexRoberts See the edit, please. The additional code should make the comma go away.

Comment: @AlexRoberts Maïeul has pushed a new version of `biblatex-source-division` to CTAN. With the new version my modified version of `getsourcedivision` is not needed any more.

Comment: I just downloaded it and tested it, and it works on my system too. Thanks again for making this work.